# how to close $.colorbox from inside the frame

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I am using colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js.
I have the following code(below) which works fine.
I am trying to figure out how to close this from inside the iframe.
From the FAQ, I tried 
`onClick='parent.$.colorbox.close(); return false;'`
but got the error `Permission denied to access property '$'`

Thanks for any help.

```
$(".iframepop").colorbox({
    width:"630px", height:"650px", iframe:true, overlayClose: false, fastIframe: false,
    onOpen:function(){ 
        iframeID = $(this).attr("id");
    },
    onLoad:function(){
        $('#secureContent').animate({width: "600px"}, 'fast');
    },
    onCleanup:function(){ 
    },
    onClosed:function(){ 
        switch($(this).attr("id")){
            case 'goto_home':
                window.location = "/secure/iframeredirect.php";
                break;
            case 'goto_myaccount':
                document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
                window.location = "/myaccount";
                break;

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe try `parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();` instead?

Comment: no joy.. 
Permission denied to access property 'jQuery'

Line 1

Answer (score 0):

you can use $('#cboxClose').remove(); to close the colorbox from inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` just removes the close button, use `$('#cboxClose').click();`